# ECSlidingViewController Remove Bounce Animation when selecting menu item

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation, ecslidingviewcontroller

When you open and close the menu with the button it just snaps shut, however, when you click on an item withing the menu it bounces to the other side and then back again.

Although this is a nice effect it does not work so will with what I am doing presently, can this be disabled?  I simply want it to snap shut when the user clicks a menu item.

EDIT

The code in didSelectecItemAtIndex is

```
UIViewController *newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
[self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECLeft animations:nil onComplete:^{
        CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController = newTopViewController;
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
        [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
    }];
```

Comment: Show which code you're using. Did you try changing the animation / method you're calling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem but I found the solution. Here is my code:

```
[self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECANCELED animations:nil onComplete:^{
            ObjHomeView.navigationItem.title=[[dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Menu_Name"];
            CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
            self.slidingViewController.topViewController = ObjHomeView;
            self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
            [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
        }];
```

Here

```
[self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewoffScreenTo:ECANCELED animations:nil onComplete:^{
 You can put your code

}];
```

just put the argument `ECCANCELED` . I hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I am struggling to implement it (a little new to this), could you give a little more detail?

Answer (score 1):

`anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:animations:onComplete:` and `resetTopView` are methods that cause the top view to move.

It sounds like you just want to set a new `topViewController` and `resetTopView` like this:

```
UIViewController *newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
self.slidingViewController.topViewController = newTopViewController;
self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
[self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
```

Comment: Thanks this helped, except for the resetTopView (-[InitViewController resetTopView]: unrecognized selector sent) anyway usefull post +1